# Simple complex question

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $$\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|<1$$
for $|z|<1$, $|w|<1$
How I do it:
First notice that:

$\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|<1 \leftrightarrow |z-w| < |1-\overline{z}w|$
Since $$|z-w|<|z-w|||\overline{z}| = |z^2-\overline{z}w| < |1-\overline{z}w|$$ we are done. The professor said this one might be a bit tricky though so I'm wondering if I did something wrong because this seemed pretty straightforward, no?

Comment: The first inequality only holds if $|z| >1$.

Comment: @Hetebrij I added the conditions $|z|<1, |w|<1$.

Comment: Still, if we have $|z| = \frac{1}{2}$ and $w=0$, then we have $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{4}$ in the first inequality.

Comment: The inequality holds for all $(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ with $|z|, |w| < 1$ or $|z|, |w| > 1$, as is discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/787597/39599). This is not a duplicate of that question though.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Please note the added conditions.

Comment: @Lozansky Micheal states that your inequality is true, and in fact is also true if $|z|,|w|>1$.

Comment: Your argument is not quite correct: on the bottom line, you mean $|z|^2$, not $z^2$, I believe.

Comment: @user264781 Ah yes, that's what I meant. The next step should follow then?

Comment: @Lozansky Do you know Maximum Modulus theorem?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, yes, and that's "if and only if", as the inequality is equivalent to $(|z|^2-1)(|w|^2-1)>0$.

Comment: @Lozansky, it follows, but I think needs some more explanation. Consider what values the real part of $\overline{z}w$ can take.

Comment: @Learner No don't think so.

Comment: @user264781 Hm how does that matter? It will be between -1 and 1 at least.

Comment: @Lozansky Suppose $|z|^2=0.5$ and $\overline{z}w=0.9$. Then the inequality would be false. This can't happen, but you need to show why, I don't think its clear that $\overline{z}w$ is closer to $|z|^2$ than to 1.

Comment: @user264781 But I only use that $|z^2|$<1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove if $|z| &lt; 1$ and $ |w| &lt; 1$, then $|1-zw^*| \neq 0$ and $| {{z-w} \over {1-zw^*}}| &lt; 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343982/prove-if-z-1-and-w-1-then-1-zw-neq-0-and-z-w-over-1)